# Emulating google search with elasticsearch (fuzzy, phrase, handle sloppy queries) -- am I doing it right?

Tags: elasticsearch

We are replacing google site search with elastic and trying to match all the functionality (prefix searches, phrase searches, fuzzy search + spell correction, multilingual).  After a few tries I've got a decent solution which combines match_phrase_prefix, query_string, and (demoted) fuzzy_like_this.  I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this?

Below is my settings for dutch and an example query.

```
"settings":{
    "analysis":{
        "filter":{
            "nl_stop_filter":{
                "stopwords":[
                    "_dutch_"
                ],
                "type":"stop"
            },
            "nl_stem_filter":{
                "type":"stemmer",
                "name":"dutch"
            }
        },
        "analyzer":{
            "article_analyzer":{
                "filter":[
                    "icu_normalizer",
                    "nl_stop_filter",
                    "icu_folding"
                ],
                "type":"custom",
                "tokenizer":"icu_tokenizer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

query:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "match_phrase_prefix": {
                            "_all": "je telefoon nummer"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "je telefoon nummer"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "fuzzy_like_this": {
                            "like_text": "je telefoon nummer",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                            "boost": 0.5
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "fields": {
        "title": {
            "fragment_size": 300,
            "number_of_fragments": 1
        },
        "body": {
            "fragment_size": 150,
            "number_of_fragments": 2
        }
    }
}
```